# How to get only the URL using regex on Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: regex, string, url, yahoo-pipes

for example, I have some feed, with an item title like this

**Some text is better than one text http://t.co/blablabla  #hashtag**

then I want to get only the URL using regex like this

**http://t.co/blablabla**

how do i do that ?

Comment: do you want to split this based on how much their words..? I think it called substring. Sorry, but I dont catch the point of this question. Maybe you can write it more specific, it is like what language do you work on? or anything.

Comment: @andikurnia Yahoo Pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
http:\/\/t.co\/[^\s]+
```

http://regex101.com/r/pK6lW5

Comment: If I use this regex to Regex module on Yahoo pipes, The string will show Some text is better than one text #hashtag (without http://t.co/blablabla)


In my question, I want to get only the URL using regex module or the result only like this

http://t.co/blablabla